# How to make Render Trigger Manual in SharpGL/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpgl

I've installed SharpGL control for WPF. The control is always in Render Loop by which I mean it renders in certain intervals. What I want is a one time draw. Because I'm not making a game and I don't need the scene to be rendered constantly. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

set RenderTrigger to manual and call openGLControl.DoRender(); once.

```
openGLControl.RenderTrigger = RenderTrigger.Manual;
openGLControl.DoRender();
```